# ¿Es posible llamar un procedimiento almacenado dentro de un select?

Tags: mysql, sql, funciones, stored-procedure, callback

Tengo el siguiente PA (`promedio_ventas`) que me trae el promedio de ventas de un producto, por lo cual, recibe como dato de entrada el id del producto que quiero consultar (`p_id_producto`):

```
SET monto_ventas = (SELECT sum(p.precio) from ventas v WHERE id_producto = p_id_producto);
SET ventas = (SELECT count(p.id_venta) from ventas v WHERE id_producto = p_id_producto);
SET promedio = (monto_ventas/ventas);
```

El segundo PA (`productos`) me trae la información de todos mis productos y no recibe parámetros:

```
SELECT p.id_producto, p.producto, p.descripcion FROM productos p;
```

Requiero que en mi consulta de productos, cada producto me traiga su promedio de ventas.

Puedo llamar un PA desde otro con la sentencia `CALL promedio_ventas(p_id_producto)` , sin embargo requiero que el promedio sea para cada artículo en mi lista de productos.

¿Es posible llamar el pa dentro del select?
Se me ocurre algo como:

```
SELECT p.id_producto,
p.producto,
p.descripcion,
CALL promedio_ventas(p.id_producto)
FROM productos p;
```

Sin embargo esto no es correcto y no funciona en MySQL.

Podría realizar el cálculo dentro del mismo sp de productos, sin embargo el cálculo para lo que lo requiero es muy grande y generaría un `SELECT` enorme.

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Eso, se puede resolver simplemente en un solo query... lo probaste? no estas haciendo nada raro, ni nada que no se solucione con un group by....